# Is there a way in numpy to test whether a matrix is Unitary

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, fft

I was wondering if there is any function in numpy to determine whether a matrix is Unitary?

This is the function I wrote but it is not working. I would be thankful if you guys can find an error in my function and/or tell me another way to find out if a given matrix is unitary.

```
def is_unitary(matrix: np.ndarray) -> bool:

    unitary = True
    n = matrix.size
    error = np.linalg.norm(np.eye(n) - matrix.dot( matrix.transpose().conjugate()))

    if not(error < np.finfo(matrix.dtype).eps * 10.0 *n):
        unitary = False

    return unitary
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take an obviously unitary array:

```
>>> a = 0.7
>>> b = (1-a**2)**0.5
>>> m = np.array([[a,b],[-b,a]])
>>> m.dot(m.conj().T)
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

and try your function on it:

```
>>> is_unitary(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-28-8dc9ddb462bc>", line 1, in <module>
    is_unitary(m)
  File "<ipython-input-20-3758c2016b67>", line 5, in is_unitary
    error = np.linalg.norm(np.eye(n) - matrix.dot( matrix.transpose().conjugate()))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,4) (2,2)
```

which happens because

```
>>> m.size
4
>>> np.eye(m.size)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

If we replace `n = matrix.size` with `len(m)` or `m.shape[0]` or something, we get

```
>>> is_unitary(m)
True
```

I might just use

```
>>> np.allclose(np.eye(len(m)), m.dot(m.T.conj()))
True
```

where `allclose` has `rtol` and `atol` parameters.

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't made available in `numpy`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using NumPy's [matrix class](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), there is a property for the Hermitian conjugate, so:

```
def is_unitary(m):
    return np.allclose(np.eye(m.shape[0]), m.H * m)
```

e.g.

```
In [79]: P = np.matrix([[0,-1j],[1j,0]])

In [80]: is_unitary(P)
Out[80]: True
```