# How to get an unitary matrix from pytorch

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

I need a parameterized **unitary matrix** for my optimization problems **using PyTorch**, so how do I generate such a matrix by PyTorch, or how do I ensure that the matrix is unitary during the optimization process?

The main problem is that an n-dimensional unitary matrix or we can say that this matrix is ***SU(n)***  is parameterized by **n^2-1** parameters, so how can I get this matrix by **only** n^2-1 parameters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch is very similar to numpy, you can check solutions for numpy and adapt that to pytorch.

To check if a `torch.Tensor` is **unitary** you can write something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997244/is-there-a-way-in-numpy-to-test-whether-a-matrix-is-unitary):

```
torch.allclose(torch.eye(len(m)), torch.matmul(m , m.T.conj()).float())
```

Where `m` is the matrix that you want to check. Note the similarity with the numpy implementation.

For the generation part, you can use something like `scipy` or just basic `numpy`, then you can cast the array to tensor using `torch.from_numpy()` [function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html).